# How do you create a v8::ObjectTemplate with an array property?

Tags: v8, embedded-v8

I am trying to create an ObjectTemplate that contains a property that is an array of ObjectTemplates.  My goal is to use this ObjectTemplate to construct a v8::Context that will have a property that is an array of objects.

```
v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> t = v8::ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);
v8::Local<v8::Array> a = v8::Array::New(isolate, 3);
v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> i0 = v8::ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);
i0->Set(isolate, "a", v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "hello"));
i0->Set(isolate, "b", v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "goodbye"));
a->Set(0, i0); // <== This is where compile error occurs
```

This fails to compile with this error message:

```
error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'v8::ObjectTemplate *' to 'v8::Value *volatile '
```

As a work-around I tried this but the resulting object is not an array!

```
v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> t = v8::ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);
v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> i0 = v8::ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);
i0->Set(isolate, "a", v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "hello"));
i0->Set(isolate, "b", v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "goodbye"));
t->Set(isolate, "0", i0);

v8::Local<v8::Object> o;
if (t->NewInstance(context).ToLocal(&o))
{
  v8::Local<v8::Value> x = o->Get(0);
  if (x->IsArray())
  {
    std::cout << "It is an array" << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "It is not an array" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Think of "ObjectTemplate" as a "blueprint". For `a->Set(0, i0);`, you need `i0` to be an actual Object, not a blueprint/template. If you replace:

```
v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> i0 = v8::ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);
i0->Set(isolate, "a", v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "hello"));
i0->Set(isolate, "b", v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "goodbye"));
```

with:

```
v8::Local<v8::Object> i0 = v8::Object::New(isolate);
i0->Set(context, v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "a"), 
        v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "hello"));
i0->Set(context, v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "b"),
        v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "goodbye"));
```

where `context` is a `v8::Local<v8::Context>`, then that should make your code work.

(Side note: the line `a->Set(0, i0);` won't work with newer V8 versions, because that particular overload of `Set` has been deprecated and removed. It needs a `context` now.)